# VBA Copy value to another worksheet with autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to copy the value from current sheet to another workbooks with auto filter by creating new one, once I run the code I got the error:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

Here's the code:

```
Sub copyvaluetoanothersheet()
Dim selectrange As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

Set Dsheet = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Lastrow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    selectrange = Sheet2.Range("A2:BP" & Lastrow)

    With Worksheets("Production data")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    selectrange.AutoFilter field:="Branch", Criteria1:="Direct Response"
    selectrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy

End With
    Dsheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) when assigning object variables (you've done it elsewhere).

`Set selectrange = Sheet2.Range("A2:BP" & Lastrow)`

Note too that your mixture of sheet code names, tab names, and indexes is confusing, and that your code will error if nothing is visible.

Comment: Thanks SJR, I think I found the problem, re-writing now

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Sub cpVisible()
Dim MyProdName As String
Dim FilteredRange As Range
Dim myArr As Variant

    Sheets("Production Data").Range("$A$2:$BP$50000").AutoFilter Field:="Branch", Criteria1:="Direct Response"
    Set FilteredRange = Sheets("Production Data").Range("$A$2:$BP$50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    FilteredRange.Copy Sheets("Dsheet").Range("A1")

End Sub
```